# Flow: Internal Error: Unexpected class static type: ObjProtoT

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I try to generate flow typings for my small library written with flow, but I have this error:

```
-> % flow gen-flow-files src --out-dir dist
Found 14 files, generating libdefs...
Error: Failure("./src/types.js: Failure(\"Internal Error: Unexpected class static type: ObjProtoT\")")
```

If I run only check:

```
-> % flow
No errors!
```

./src/types.js -> https://gist.github.com/orlov-vo/1d889cbb22ab397b2c2af7e1d3e46dd1

What is wrong?